# Cloud functions to update data from Realtime to firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have some data in realtime database which are taken from IOT sensors i want to store some of the data in firestore i did this code

```
exports.addtoFirestore = functions.database.ref('lamps/{id}').onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const val = snapshot.val();
    const id = snapshot.key;

    return admin.firestore().collection('lamps').doc(id).update({
        Humidity: val.Humidity,
        Temperature: val.Temperature
      });

    

     


});
```

But the function console prints **Function execution took 76 ms, finished with status: 'error' ** when updating the realtime database

Answer (score 1):

There are three main issues with your code:

- By using [`DocumentReference#update(newData)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) to sync the changes with Cloud Firestore, your code will throw an error if the `/lamps/{id}` document doesn't exist in your Cloud Firestore.
- Because you are using an [`onWrite()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-write) RTDB trigger, you need to handle the case where the data that the Cloud Function points at has been deleted. Currently your function will error-out if it doesn't exist (as `val == null`).
- If either `Humidity` or `Temperature` (case sensitive!) are omitted from the incoming data, trying to add their data to Cloud Firestore (which will be `undefined`) will throw an error about an invalid data type.

The easiest fix for this would be to use [`DocumentReference#set(newData, { merge: true })`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) and [`DocumentReference#delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete) as appropriate while securing your RTDB with [suitable security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database) to make sure your incoming data is well-shaped.

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addtoFirestore = functions.database.ref('lamps/{id}').onWrite(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const id = snapshot.key;
  const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('lamps').doc(id);

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    // data deleted, delete linked Firestore data
    return docRef.delete()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Failed to sync data deletion for /lamps/${id}: `, error);

        // optionally rethrow it:
        // throw error;
      });
  }

  const { Humidity, Temperature } = snapshot.val();
  return docRef.set({ Humidity, Temperature }, { merge: true })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Failed to sync data to Firestore for /lamps/${id}: `, error);

      // optionally rethrow it:
      // throw error;
    });
});
```

Make sure to implement the associated security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lamps": {
      "$lampId": {
        // must be logged in to read/write
        // because we restrict this heavily below, you
        // could make this "true", but I don't recommend it
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".read": "auth != null",

        "Humidity": {
          // if present, must be number
          ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
        },
        "Temperature": {
          // if present, must be number
          ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
        },
        "$other": {
          // block all other data
          ".validate": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Other Notes:**

- Even with the above changes, you can use Cloud Firestore and the RTDB in the same project and at the same time, so you could cut out this sync function entirely and just connect to both databases on the client. This will reduce the any out-of-sync problems that will arise from using this function.
- You could also consider a on-demand "sync changes" function that is either [scheduled to run every X minutes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) or expose a [HTTP endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that syncs the changes less frequently if you are expecting to have many sensors updating the RTDB at once.